# Grouping Windows in the tasklist

Tags: awesome-wm, tasklist

I'm currently using the icon-only style tasklist from [here](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/awful.widget.tasklist.html) on all tags. This gives me a nice overview of everything that's running on my system. If I have a lot of programs running the taskbar tends to get messy rather quickly.

[image: Taskbar]

I was wondering if there's a way to group windows by class. To have for example all firefox windows next to each other, all terminals next to each other, etc. Another nice option might be to have them all stacked on top of each other - for example to have only 1 terminal icon in the taskbar that holds all terminal sub processes accessible in a popup menu. I tried to come up with something for both options but unfortunately it's beyond my knowledge :)

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not actually helpful, so I am not writing it as an answer, but: Yes, this is possible in theory. The C code exports all the necessary information to Lua. However, I do not think that the existing `tasklist` Lua code has any already existing support for grouping entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually... yes this is kind of possible with the existing code. The function `awful.widget.tasklist` gets a table as its first argument. The entry `source` is used to get the list of clients that should be displayed (and `filter` is used to select only a subset of them, e.g. those on the currently selected tag).

The default for `source` is `awful.widget.tasklist.source.all_clients` which just returns `client.get()` (all clients that exist). If you replace this with a function that only returns one client per class, then you'd get what you want.

However, this could interact with the `filter`. For example, if you have XTerms one another tag and on the current tag, then filtering  in the `source` function could mean that one selects the client on another tag and `filter` then gets rid of that as well. So, I guess it makes more sense to have the `filter` do this, but the filter does not see the list of all clients, but only a single one.

One possible approach is to already call the `filter` in the `source` function. Untested sketch:

```lua
s.mytasklist = awful.widget.tasklist {
    screen = s,
    filter = function() return true end, -- Filtering is already done in source
    source = function()
        -- Get all clients
        local cls = client.get()

        -- Filter by an existing filter function and allowing only one client per class
        local result = {}
        local class_seen = {}
        for _, c in pairs(cls) do
            if awful.widget.tasklist.filter.currenttags(c, s) then
                if not class_seen[c.class] then
                    class_seen[c.class] = true
                    table.insert(result, c)
                end
            end
        end
        return result
    end,
}
```

The above code would mean that only the first client of each class is displayed. If you want e.g. a popup menu to open when clicking an entry representing more than one class, you will some more code. This answer only handles the "look", not the "behaviour".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Thanks for taking the time to explain - it cleared up a lot of things. 

Visually the only thing that is missing is that the focus indicator in the task list gets lost if I focus on another window other than the first one. I was trying to see if I could find a way to pass the window class to the widget_template instead of the actual client but I wasn't successful.

What would you recommend is a good approach for the popup? Not sure if it would best to start from the awful.popup api tasklist example and try to filter only by window class...

Comment: Hm... Checking if a client has the focus is `client.focus == c`. Perhaps the `source` function should be changed so that it always uses the focused client if one exist? Random idea for that would be to change `class_seen[c.class] = true` to `class_seen[c.class] = #result` and append an `elseif client.focus == c then result[class_seen[c.class]] = c` to the inner-most `if`. This remembers the position of each "class" in `result` and uses that to overwrite the entry when the focused client "comes by".

Comment: Thanks! I tried to implement your answer but the behavior is still the same. My inner most `if` looks like this now: `if not class_seen[c.class] then class_seen[c.class] = #result table.insert(result, c) elseif client.focus == c then result[class_seen[c.class]] = c end`

Comment: Actually, there is an off-by-one error, right? Lua tables start indices at 1, so it needs to be `#result + 1` (or alternatively: computing `#result` after `table.insert` changed the table length.

Comment: Ahh that totally makes sense! Yes, this works now as expected :) Thank you so much! As for the list popup do you have any pointers?

Comment: Hm... Nope, not really. There is a call to `awful.menu.client_list` in the default config. You could look at the code for `client_list` and write something similar yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint - this was a great help! You really helped me learn a lot here, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Uli's answer to combine multiple clients I'm using the code below to generate a popup menu if there is more than 1 client of a certain class inside my `tasklist_buttons`. If there are more efficient ways of doing this please feel free to let me know :) I'm still a novice.

```
awful.button({ }, 1, function (c)

    if cl_menu then
        cl_menu:hide()
        cl_menu=nil
    else
        client_num=0
        client_list={}
        for i, cl in pairs(client.get()) do
            if cl.class == c.class then
                client_num = client_num + 1
                client_list[i]=
                  {cl.name,
                   function()
                       client.focus = cl
                       awful.tag.viewonly(cl:tags()[1])
                       cl:raise()
                   end,
                   cl.icon
                  }
           end
        end

        if client_num > 1 then
            cl_menu=awful.menu({items = client_list, theme = {width=300}})
            cl_menu:show()
        else
            client.focus = c
            awful.tag.viewonly(c:tags()[1])
            c:raise() 
        end
    end
end),
```

Comment: `if awful.rules.match(cl, {class= c.class}) then` is just `if cl.class == c.class then`

Comment: Ah yep, thanks! Makes sense. Updated the code above.